# How to use EditText onClick method while remaining focused

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` that has a `ListPopupWindow` attached to it with recent search queries listed.  When a user clicks the `EditText`, the popup should show, then when the user starts typing, the popup should disappear.

This is mostly working using `OnFocusChangeListener`, `OnTextChangedListener`, and `OnEditorActionListener`.  However, if a user has clicked on the `EditText`, began to type, then clicks the `EditText` again, I need the popup to come back up.  I have tried using an `OnClickListener` instead of an `OnFocusChangeListener` but can never get the popup to show with an `OnClickListener`.

**How can I get the `ListPopUpWindow` to show when the use clicks the `EditText` if it already has focus?**

```
searchBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean gainFocus) {
        //onFocus
        if (gainFocus) {
            popUpWindow.show();
        }
    }
});
```

To dismiss popup once user start typing in EditText field

```
searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        popUpWindow.dismiss();
    }
});
```

To clear focus, dismiss popup, and execute search

```
searchBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((actionId & v.getImeOptions()) == actionId) {
            if (event != null && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (searchBox.getText().toString().length() == 0) return true;
                searchBox.clearFocus();
                popUpWindow.dismiss();
                fetchResults();
                Util.hideKeyboard(v);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  It turns out I wasn't actually using an `EditText` object, but rather a custom class called `MaterialEditText` that provides a wrapper around an `EditText` object to give it Material UI features.  The class passes the listeners I had been using onto it's EditText member, however, it was not doing so for either `OnClickListener` or `OnTouchListener`, so these listeners were never getting set for the `EditText` object.  Once I added methods to pass these listeners on to the `EditText` object, I fixed my issue by keeping the code listed above and adding the following:

```
searchBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Show Popup
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the focus change listener with an on touch listener and showing the popup when a MOTION_UP event occurs:

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // Show popup here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I also made sure to setFocusableInTouchMode to true.